# How can I turn an html checkbox into an icon

Tags: html, css

I want to use HTML and CSS **only**, no JavaScript. So I put an `input type="checkbox"`, write the `ul` list, make it nice and pretty and I'm done. Now, I also have to use at least one FontAwesome icon so hey, obviously the 3 bars that everyone uses instead of the old ugly checkbox, right? I thought I could just write `<label for="menu_button" class="fas fa-bars (the icon class)"></label>` and be done with it but of course even tho it's there, it doesn't do anything, and... well, I don't know what to do.

```css
.menu_items {
  max-height: 0px;
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono";
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 28px;
  background-color: #0000EC;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu_button:checked~.menu_items {
  max-height: 224px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="navbar">
  <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="logo">
  <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <input type="checkbox" class="menu_button">
    <label for="menu_button" class="fas fa-bars"></label>
    <ul class="menu_items">
      <li href="#episodios">EPISODIOS</li>
      <li href="#nosotros">NOSOTROS</li>
      <li href="#entrevistas">ENTREVISTAS</li>
      <li href="#topicos">TÓPICOS</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`input` can be linked to a `label` via the `id` and `for` attribute , not the `class` attribute ;). It can be hidden any way you like then.

example

```css
.menu_items {
  max-height: 0px;
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono";
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 28px;
  background-color: #0000EC;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition:0.2s;
}

#burger:checked~.menu_items {
  max-height: 224px;
}
#burger {position:absolute;right:100vw;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="navbar">
  <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="logo">
  <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <input type="checkbox" class="menu_button" id="burger">
    <label for="burger" class="fas fa-bars"></label>
    <ul class="menu_items">
      <li href="#episodios">EPISODIOS</li>
      <li href="#nosotros">NOSOTROS</li>
      <li href="#entrevistas">ENTREVISTAS</li>
      <li href="#topicos">TÓPICOS</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dude, thank you so much, seriously, and also for that transition hahaha, this website is awesome!